# Vector char. Ошибка при работе с двумерным vector-ом char-ов

Tags: c++, vector

Дана задачка для решения которой хотел использовать `vector` с значениями типа `char`. При работе вылетает ошибка компиляции. Тест ошибки:

> warning: missing terminating ' character, error: missing terminating '
> character.

В чём может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int n,m;
    string s;
    cin >> n >> s;
    m = count(s.begin(), s.end(), '+');
    vector <vector<char>> map(n, vector <char>(m, '.'));
    for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
        if(s[i] == '+'){
            map[i][i] = '/';
        }
        else if (s[i] == '-' && s[i-1] != '-'){
            map[i][i-1] = '\';
            if(s[i+1] == '-'){
                --i;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j){
            cout << map[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Забавно, подсветка кода на сайте подсказывает, где ошибка. `'\'` -> `'\\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен в строке символ `\` - то его надо вводить как `'\\'`.

Символ `\` в С/С++ используется как экранирующий, позволяющий записывать в строки "непечатные" символы - типа, `\t` - табуляция, `\n` - символ новой строки...

Соответственно, сам по себе `\` оказывается ошибкой...

См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло!